# Adding dynamic string to logger format

Tags: python, logging, formatting

I am trying to add a dynamic string to a formatter but unable to do so.

Here is the code.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')

var = 'some vaue'
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s %s' % var)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.error('error message')
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 8, in <module>
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s %s' % var)
TypeError: format requires a mapping
```

here

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s %s' % var)
```

is what causing the error, i really need to add a varible var to this format.

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s simple_example')
```

works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s {0}'.format(var))
```

You can learn more here
http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: Thanks it work. Please remove 'simple_example' from your answer